# javascript_tag and <script> tag are being stripped from erb templates

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, tags, erb

I am a Ruby/Rails noob and have just started working on a legacy Rails app that's running on Passenger using ree-1.8.7.

My issue is that every time I add javascript_tag calls or  tags to some .erb templates, they always get stripped out of the final output when the page renders in browser, but only on some of the views, not all. I am trying to find where that setting may be configured, but can't find anything.

The templates are in subdirectories of app/views, both ones that work and ones that don't work.

For example, if I put a simple snipped like this

```
<%= javascript_tag "
    var test='test'
" %>
```

in the browser page source i never see generated javascript where as if i put it in "good" erb files, it is seen.

Comment: Do you have something like this http://blog.hulihanapplications.com/browse/view/10-strip-html-in-ruby-on-rails For some of your views?

Comment: It would be helpful if you showed relevant code examples and describe as much as you can about the result.

Comment: Juan, I don't have anything like that in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Your file may be named incorrectly. `show.html.erb` right? What version of rails too?

Comment: In my case it's just .erb files, like index.erb or _index.erb, but i've tried renaming them and it didn't matter. Version of rails is 2.3.14

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured this out. 
This was due to PrototypeJS making Ajax calls, and by default they strip javascript tags in the response. More on this here:

https://groups.google.com/d/msg/prototype-scriptaculous/ox5KB9rJ8cc/IzXqd4eOWRgJ